# Allocate unallocated space to ext4

Tags: xubuntu, unallocated

[image]
How to allocate 48gb space you see in this picture to ext4 linux partition? so total i would have 148gb in total please help

Comment: You need to boot a live session and use goarted to 1. Move one partition to the right, then 2. Grow the other partition

Comment: sorry can you tell me in brief about grow other partition? sorry im not really into these stuff. Thank you :)

Comment: If you don't understand partitions perhaps beter to leave them alone？Nothing about managing partitions is without risk！

Comment: First make sure you have backups. Then start by understanding that you can only expand a partition if there's unallocate space contiguous to its end, reason why you need to move one partition fir that matter.

Comment: Make a backup before doing anything. And do a little search about dealing with partitions (i've just googled a little but you can google more):
 - https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted
 - https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions

Answer (score 1):

1. Move sda6 to the right.
2. Select sda9 and extend it to the right.

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** sda6 partition all the way to the right
- **resize** the right side of sda9 all the way to the right
- click the Apply icon
- reboot